# Windows server service bus 1.1 in server explorer Connection string error

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, servicebus, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I installed service bus in my Windows server 2012, using the Service bus Power shell. After that while trying to connect via the VS2012, its throwing an error " The underlying connection was closed.Cannot establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel". 
I am trying to connect in the same server on which the service bus was installed..

Please help!!!!

Comment: Can you add the code you're using to connect? The connection string would be useful. Have you checked the 4 services are running in the server (Service Bus Gateway, SB Message Broker, SB Resource Provider, Windows Fabric Host Service)? Where did you get the connection string from? I also found I needed to install Service Bus while logged in as the same account that the services use to login as. You should also try using the Service Bus Explorer 2.1.3.0 to verify if you can connect. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2014/12/04/service-bus-explorer-2-5-now-available.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help!! but the issue was with the certiification error as well as incorrct dll that has been added..